# How to make fields on my model not searchable but they should still be available in the _source?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

I am using the tire gem for ElasticSearch in Rails.

Ok so I have been battling with this the whole day and this is how far I have got. I would like to make fields on my model not searchable but they should still be available in the _source so I can use them for sorting on the search result.

My mappings:

```
mapping do
indexes :created_at, :type => 'date', :index => :not_analyzed
indexes :vote_score, :type => 'integer', :index => :not_analyzed
indexes :title
indexes :description
indexes :tags
indexes :answers do
indexes :description
end
end
```

My to_indexed_json method:

```
def to_indexed_json
{
vote_score: vote_score,
created_at: created_at,
title: title,
description: description,
tags: tags,
answers: answers.map{|answer| answer.description}
}.to_json
end
```

My Search query:

```
def self.search(term='', order_by, page: 1)
tire.search(page: page, per_page: PAGE_SIZE, load: true) do
query { term.present? ? string(term) : all }
sort {
by case order_by
when LAST_POSTED then {created_at: 'desc'}
else {vote_score: 'desc', created_at: 'desc'}
end
}
end
end
```

The only issue I am battling with now is how do I make **vote_score** and **created_at** field not searchable but still manage to use them for sorting when I'm searching.

I tried `indexes :created_at, :type => 'date', :index => :no` but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, you are not specifying a field when you send your search query to elasticsearch. This means it will be executed agains the `_all` field. This is a "special" field that makes elasticsearch a little easier to get using quickly. By default all fields are indexed twice, once in their own field, and once in the `_all` field. (You can even have different mappings/analyzers applied to these two indexings.)

I think setting the field's mappings to `"include_in_all": "false"` should work for you (remove the `"index": "no"` part). Now the field will be tokenized (and you can search with it) under it's fieldname, but when directing a search at the `_all` field it won't affect results (as none of it's tokens are stored in the `_all` field).

[Have a read of the es docs on mappings, scroll down to the parameters for each type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/core-types/)

Good luck!

Comment: I have set indexes :created_at, :type => 'date', :include_in_all => false on those fields but their values still appear to be searchable even when its not under the fieldname. Which means either I'm still missing something else or include_in_all => false is not the correct approach. For example, I typed in 2013 as my query and I get results , which I believe are coming from the created_at field.

Comment: You have to reindex after changing the mapping. (I guess you might have done this, just making sure)

Comment: Yes I have reindexed and still getting the same issue. Even after further reading :include_in_all => false seems to be all I need but those fields are still searchable. Is there anything else I could be missing?

Comment: I ended up going with the approach of only matching on the fields I want and that worked. This matches on multiple fields.

tire.search(page: page, per_page: PAGE_SIZE, load: true) do
      query { term.present? ? (match [:title, :description, :tags, :answers], term) : all }
      sort {
        by case order_by
             when LAST_POSTED then {created_at: 'desc'}
             else {vote_score: 'desc', created_at: 'desc'}
           end
      }
    end

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit lost as to why you're still seeing hits. If you could try a few curl statements from the command line you might be able to suss it out.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with the approach of only matching on the fields I want and that worked. This matches on multiple fields.

```
tire.search(page: page, per_page: PAGE_SIZE, load: true) do
      query { term.present? ? (match [:title, :description, :tags, :answers], term) : all }
      sort {
        by case order_by
             when LAST_POSTED then {created_at: 'desc'}
             else {vote_score: 'desc', created_at: 'desc'}
           end
      }
    end
```